# Type conversion with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a concrete class - 'Giraffe' that implements 'IMammal'.  In my scenario, I can create a generic repository and factory like so:

```
public MammalFactory : IMammalFactory
{
    public IMammalRepository<T> GetMammalRepo<T>() where T: IMammal, new()
    {
        return new MammalRepository<T>();
    }
}
```

MammalRepository can now be of type Giraffe or Antelope as long as they both implement IMammal.  So far, so good.

However, I can't use an expression like this (won't compile and cannot cast):

```
Func<IMammalRepository<IMammal>> = () => this.factory.GetMammalRepo<Giraffe>();
```

I have a method that is very similar between my classes and I want to factor them down to something like:

```
//called from different implementations
public void FeedAnimalInternal(Func<IMammalRepository<IMammal>> repo, Action<IMammal> doIt)
{
    var animalRepo = repo();
    var animals = animalRepo.GetAnimals(); //might be giraffe or might be something else
    foreach (var animal in animals) { doIt(animal); }
}
```

First, why won't the Func<> (first one) compile?  Is this a covariance thing?  Next, any idea how I can accomplish something similar to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a covariance thing. If you define `IMammalRepository` like this:

```
public interface IMammalRepository<out T> where T : IMammal
{
    // ...
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yep.  I need to read more on covariance and contravariance it appears.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Eric Lippert's blog [posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=Covariance%20and%20Contravariance%20in%20C#&beta=0&rn=Fabulous%20Adventures%20In%20Coding&rq=site%3ablogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/&ac=4) on [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx). It is a ten part series I think.